# Complex-number inequality $| z_1 z_2 \ldots z_m - 1 | \leq e^{|z_1 - 1| + \ldots + |z_m - 1|} - 1$

Tags: complex-numbers, inequality

Let $z_1, z_2 \ldots z_m$ be complex numbers, $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Can anybody tell me how to prove the following inequality?

$| z_1 z_2 \ldots z_m - 1 | \leq e^{|z_1 - 1| + \ldots + |z_m - 1|} - 1$

In case you're wondering, this is asserted without proof in a paper by Von Neumann, about infinite tensor products of Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The inequality in question bounds how far you can get from $1$ by multiplying several complex numbers that may individually not be far from $1$. So it makes sense to try to derive a bound for the product of just *two* complex numbers, and then proceed by induction.

**Lemma:** Suppose $\lvert z_1 - 1\rvert = \alpha_1$ and $\lvert z_2 - 1\rvert = \alpha_2$. Then $\lvert z_1 z_2 - 1\rvert \le (1 + \alpha_1)(1 + \alpha_2) - 1$.

**Proof:** We know $\alpha_1\alpha_2 = \lvert z_1z_2 - z_1 - z_2 + 1\rvert$. By triangle inequality on the three points $z_1 z_2$, $z_1 + z_2 - 1$, and $1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\lvert z_1 z_2 - 1\rvert &\le \lvert z_1 z_2 - z_1 - z_2 + 1\rvert + \lvert z_1 + z_2 - 2\rvert \\
&\le \alpha_1\alpha_2 + \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \\
&= (1 + \alpha_1)(1 + \alpha_2) - 1.
\end{align}$$

Now, for several numbers,
$$\begin{align}
\lvert z_1 z_2 \cdots z_m - 1\rvert &\le (1 + \alpha_1)(1 + \alpha_{2,\ldots,m}) - 1 \\
&\le (1 + \alpha_1)(1 + \alpha_2)(1 + \alpha_{3,\ldots,m}) - 1 \\
&\vdots \\
&\le (1 + \alpha_1)(1 + \alpha_2)\cdots(1 + \alpha_m) - 1,
\end{align}$$ where $\alpha_{2,\ldots,m}$, for example, is my hopefully transparent abuse of notation to denote $\lvert z_2\cdots z_m - 1\rvert.$ Finally, since $1+x \le e^x$ for real $x$, the desired inequality follows.

Comment: @Moron: Is this some sort of standard, well-known proof? It feels like a quite general and useful result, that it took me way more work to derive from scratch than it ought to have. (In my first attempt I weakened the inequality too much in the lemma, and couldn't get anywhere.)

Comment: Oops, I meant to type *that took me* without the *it* in between.

Comment: I have a feeling it is pretty standard (also supported by the paper stating it as a fact), but I am unable to place where I might have come across it. I had to derive it myself too, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, the paper describes the inequality as "easily verifiable" rather than "standard".

Comment: I don't think it's standard, but I've come across versions of it as an Olympiad-style practice problem.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This answer is wrong.

It all boils down to the inequality $|xy-1| \leq |x-1|+|y-1|$, which I expect to be true.

Given this inequality, prove by induction that

$|z_1\cdots z_m - 1| \leq |z_1 - 1| + \cdots + |z_m - 1|$.

Now use $e^x \geq 1 + x$.

Comment: the first inequality is not true: take $x=3$ and $y=2$

Comment: No, I've already tried that but I don't think it works. Take e.g. $x = y = 2$.